# How to execute a transformers python script through nodejs and containerize it?

Tags: python, node.js, dockerfile, integration, huggingface-transformers

I have a text statement in nodejs which i want to send to python,apply transformers and process it and then retrieve the processed text back into nodejs. Then to write a dockerfile and containerise the integrated code into a single container.
The dockerfile,python script and nodejs codes are attached.
The nodejs code:

```
const questions = JSON.stringify('Hello World machine learning dynamic learning advanced neural nets techs')
const pythonprocess = spawn('python3',["./py_mo2.py"],{
  shell: true,
  env:{
  ...process.env
  }
});
console.log("before process")
pythonprocess.stdout.on('data',(data) => {
    console.log(data.toString());
});
console.log("nodejs is working")
```

The python code:

```
import sys
import json
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
text=sys.argv[1]
from transformers import pipeline
summarizer=pipeline('summarization',model='lidiya/bart-base-samsum')
print(json.dumps(summarizer(text)))
```

The dockerfile code:

```
FROM python:3.7
ENV VIRTUAL_ENV=/app/venv
RUN python3 -m venv $VIRTUAL_ENV
ENV PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"
ENV NVM_DIR /usr/local/nvm
ENV NODE_VERSION 16.19.0
RUN mkdir -p $NVM_DIR
WORKDIR $NVM_DIR
RUN apt-get update && curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install nodejs
ENV NODE_PATH $NVM_DIR/node/lib/node_modules
ENV PATH="$NVM_DIR/node/bin:$PATH"
WORKDIR /app/venv
COPY requirements.txt /app/venv/
RUN . /app/venv/bin/activate && pip3 install -r requirements.txt
COPY package*.json /app/venv/
RUN npm install 
COPY . /app/venv/
CMD /usr/bin/node /app/venv/nomo.js
```

I tried experimenting using multi-stage builds in dockerfile,to install python on node image and vice versa.Am able to get a simple text output from the python code in the absence of the transformers library.Once i use it the container just exits after running the nodejs code but no output from the python code.

Thank you for the help! kudos

Comment: Thanks for your question! [Please don't post screenshots of text/data/code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/15405732). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question/answer. If you select it and click the {} button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.